# I cant get this React CSS layout to be position: fixed; bottom: 0; correctly

Tags: css, reactjs, positioning

I created a [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-fog-75nwm?file=/src/index.css:2047-2055) for this.
The problem is that I want to have the text under the images to be in a single line and I have tried to change this:

```
.timeline-carousel__item-inner {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 45px;
}
```

to this:

```
.timeline-carousel__item-inner {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

And its works making all text same position but then the Images and everything get pushed up.
Please advice?

Comment: Just need a bit of clarification, you cant have the images all of the same size right, if so how do you want to deal with the space between the text and the image? if the image is shorter than the usual size

Comment: The images width are the same and the height can be whatever. I just want the text and lines under the images to be in a straight line and not follow the image height. I would like the `<div>` holding the text under the image to be fixed and then the image row can be fixed-top if you understand, just so it look nice

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest then that you have for example the class

```
.timeline-carousel__image {
    padding-right: 30px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    min-height: 164px;
}
```

This way you are having a flex, that pushes the text away from the image, and the min-height makes sure all the containers are at least of that size, but then if you have long images, you might have a problem, its better to at least have a max height for the images or a max height to width ratio , change the min-height, to fit your need, hope this solves your issue.
Good luck

Comment: That worked for a sec then I resize window and it broke, will try something..

Comment: This only works when browser window is small when full screen it breaks

Comment: I made a [clip](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1c-rTx0HERRiJML-IqQSmEQpJAB-WFzN1/view?usp=sharing) showing what it looks like